# Django: Link data from 2 Querysets

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Im new to django and im currently making an admin panel where i can view user orders. I have two model fields

OrderItem model

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    order_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Users model

```
class Users(AbstractBaseUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

views.py

```
def admin_panel(request):
    orders=OrderItem.objects.all().order_by('-customer_id')
    context={
        'orders':orders,
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

index.html

```
{% for order in orders %}
   <tr>
   <td>{{order.order_id}}</td>
   <td>{{order.customer_id}}</td>
   <td>{{order.date_added}}</td>
   <td>{{order.product_id}}</td>
   <td>{{order.quantity}}</td>
   <td><span class="label label-success">COMPLETED</span></td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

In my views.py , instead of every customer id, how i get the actual name of the customer, based on User model?

Comment: what does this give you ? {{order.customer_id.name}}

Comment: @Kurosh Ghanizadeh it gives empty string

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, you want to collect the associated data in your view. You can make your query a little more efficient so that it collects the associated users at the same time as orders;

`orders=OrderItem.objects.select_related('customer_id').all().order_by('-customer_id')`

And then in your template, you'd do `{{ order.customer_id.name }}`.

And it's worth a note that you don't usually put a `_id` suffix on fields for FK relationships because django will do that internally, at the database level. So your database field is likely `customer_id_id`. Because in django that relationship can be traversed you'd generally just call it `customer` because you can do things like `customer.name`.

You can read a bit more on that here; https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipatterns/foreign_key_with_id_suffix.html